# What does Blue Arrow sign in display of Avaya omny sound B109 means?

Tags: device, avaya

I have Avaya omnisound B109, I don't know what happened but it started to show a blue arrow on the display and I can't turn it off or on, it has no reaction whatever I do.
How can I reset this device?[image]

Comment: This question does not appear to be [on topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by installing Avaya upgrade utility 2.8
https://support.avaya.com/downloads/download-details.action?contentId=C201891995059570_6&productId=P0968

Comment: Please do not answer [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions: [answer well-asked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is in upgrade mode. Need to push Slient->Blue tooth botton 3 times in order
[exit the upgrade mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3JRX.png)

Comment: Please do not answer [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions: [answer well-asked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).